# Как записать в ячейку MultipleInput значение Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть поле в `ActiveForm`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'question1')->widget(MultipleInput::className(), [
                                'min' => 1, // should be at least 2 rows
                                'allowEmptyList' => true,
                                'enableGuessTitle' => true,
                                'addButtonPosition' => MultipleInput::POS_HEADER, // show add button in the header

                                'columns' => [
                                    [
                                        'name' => 'name',
                                        'title' => 'Класс',
                                        'enableError' => true,
                                        'options' => [
                                            
                                            'min' => '1',
                                            'required' => 'required',
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'name' => 'umk',
                                        'title' => 'УМК',
                                        'enableError' => true,
                                        'options' => [
                                            'class' => 'form-control liter',
                                        ],
                                        'attributeOptions' => [
                                            'enableClientValidation' => true,
                                            'validateOnChange' => true,
                                            'allowEmptyList' => true,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    
                                    
                                ]

                            ])->label(false) ?>
```

Есть ячейка в базе `question1`

Когда я сохраняю через $model->save() в ячейку `question1` пишется `Array`
вот собственно почему , далее var_dump POST

```
["question1"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["umk"]=>
        string(2) "в"
      }
    }
```

Как сохранить в ячейку `question1` , данные из двух колонок (name,umk) и пробел между ними???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вам нужно преобразовать массив в строку.

```
$post = serialize( htmlspecialchars(trim(Yii::$app->request->post['name'])).' '.htmlspecialchars(trim(Yii::$app->request->post['umk'])) );
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: а так делать безопасно ??? в смысле писать $molel->name = Yii::$app->request->post['name']; Это к SQL-инъекции не приведёт? В этом вообще мой вопрос

Comment: Я показал схематически, как это сделать. А, вообще, любые входные данные нужно валидировать. Например, использовать trim() и htmlspecialchars().

Comment: Кстати, сам Yii перед отправкой данных из формы, проводит Ajax валидацию.

Comment: то есть Yii по дефолту даже  trim() и htmlspecialchars() не делает? А зачем тогда метод ->validate() и правила валидации в моделях?

Comment: Эти методы выполняют валидацию по тем правилам, которые Вы указываете в моделаях. В каждой модели есть метод rules(), Он возвращает массив, в котором указаны типы данных всех полей таблицы (string, integer), указано обязательное (required) должно быть поле или нет, какая длина (max-length) и т.д. Но саму чистку эти методы не выполяют.

Comment: спасибо за объяснения

Comment: Пожалуйста. Надеюсь, что помог хоть немного разобраться.